# Babel 6 making super constructor call to parent throws exception

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I upgraded to `babel` version 6 and I am using `"es2015", "react", "stage-0"` as presets. I am working with `react` using es6 syntax.

Everything was working fine until the upgrade. After the upgrade I started to get exceptions in places where I make super call to parent constructor.

For example for the following class:

```
class childForm extends ParentForm {
    constructor(props, context) {
        console.log("this get printed.");
        super(props, context);
        console.log("this is not printed");
    }
    ...
}

class ParentForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        console.log("this is printed");
        super(props, context);
        console.log("this is printed too");
    }

    ...
}



class AnotherComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
        myService.findById(this.props.params.id).then(result => {
             this.setState({result: result});
        }).catch(err => {
            /**** Error is catched here ******/
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    render(){
         return <div>{this.state.result && <ChildForm/>}</div>
    }
}
```

I got the following errors on the console:

```
TypeError: (0 , _typeof3.default) is not a function(…)
ReactCompositeComponent.js?cd59:443 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'context' of null(…)
```

React function that throws the error is the following function. The exception raised at `ReactCompositeComponentMixin.updateComponent`

```
  updateComponent: function (transaction, prevParentElement, nextParentElement, prevUnmaskedContext, nextUnmaskedContext) {
    var inst = this._instance;

    var nextContext = this._context === nextUnmaskedContext ? inst.context : this._processContext(nextUnmaskedContext);
    ....
```

If I carry all the functionalities of the parent class to child class, it works as expected. Do anyone encountered a similar problem?

Also is it possible to have better exception messages using some library or plugin for react?

Comment: Where's the promise which is throwing the error? Is `updateComponent` being called in a promise? Looks like `this._instance` is undefined

Comment: `TypeError: (0 , _typeof3.default) is not a function(…)` It looks like a babel bug to me. Babel 6 has some issues yet, I think every improvement is very welcome. It would be great if you provided the compiled code of those classes.

Comment: The child component is rendered after resolving a promise. I updated my question to clarify where it gets the exception.

Comment: I also get `TypeError: (0 , _typeof3.default) is not a function` after I installed [flightplan](https://github.com/pstadler/flightplan)

Comment: As an aside, you should always use a [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) on constructors that call `super` when extending 3rd party classes, in case the number of arguments changes in the future. use `constructor(props, context, ...args) { super(props, context, ...args) }`

Comment: @Tyrsius Thanks for the info, I will do that.

Comment: For me `_typeof3.default` is `{ default: { default: [Function], __esModule: true }`. I'm thinking maybe it has something to do with `babel-plugin-add-module-exports` which I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing babel-runtime@6.3.19 should solve the problem. Checkout the issue https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T6644

Answer (score 1):

This might be an issue around class compilation. It looks like it can cause an error currently if the child class is declared before the superclass.

Trying this on [babeljs.io](http://babeljs.io/repl/) currently results in an error:

```
class A extends B {
    constructor(x) {
        super(x);
    }
}

class B {
    constructor(x) {
        console.log(x);
    }
}

new A('a');
```

Try changing the order of the class definitions:

```
class ParentForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
    }
    ...
}

class childForm extends ParentForm {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
    }
    ...
}
```

**EDIT:** It seems that Chrome's classes behave pretty much the same, `Uncaught ReferenceError: B is not defined(…)` is thrown at declaration.

Comment: I am using webpack so I have all these components in different files, so I don't control the ordering of compilations. Do you suggest me downgrade to babel 5?

Comment: I think we should first make sure that this is what causes your error. Try to merge that two of your source files in the right order, and try that first.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work in either case. I still have the same error. If I log stuff, I see that my logs before calling super in child works, then my logs in parent class works too, but my log after child super constructor call is not working. Any idea?

Comment: you still get `TypeError: (0 , _typeof3.default) is not a function(…)`?

Comment: Could you show us that code? Both in compiled and not compiled form? I mean the typeof part.

Comment: I added the original versions into my question. I coldn't add the compiled version as it exceeds the limits of post. You can check them out using babeljs.io/repl. Thanks